# How to get nth letter of English alphabet in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any way to get the nth letter of the English alphabet in SQL? 
like the similar method in C#

```
 public char GetLetter(int value)
 {
     return (char) ('A' - 1 + value);
 }
```

For the above function If Value =1 it returns A. 
If Value =5 it returns E.

I need to do it in SQL. Any Suggestions ??

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', value, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Char(<inputhere> + 64)
```

Above will work for upper case characters. You will need to validate the input and see whether input is in correct range or not.

For lowercase, replace 64 with 96.

Answer (score 2):

In SQLServer try to use `CHAR` function plus `ASCII`.

```
select CHAR(ASCII('a')+ 2),CHAR(ASCII('A')+ 2)
```